# Get Property from a generic Object in C#

Tags: c#, object, get, properties, generics

have a look at this code please:

```
public void BindElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataObjects)
{
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

    foreach (T item in dataObjects)
    {
        InlineUIContainer uiContainer =
            this.CreateElementContainer(item.FirstName ????? )              
        para.Inlines.Add(uiContainer);
    }                         

    FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument(para);
    this.Document = flowDoc;
}
```

When in write in Visual Studio "item.XXX" I should get the properties from my entitiy like .FirstName or .LastName. I do not know wether dataObjects is an IEnumerable or IOrder etc... it must be generic!

**How can I get the real properties form item ? Only with Reflection?**

Comment: I thought its better than public void BindElements(object dataObjects) because than I have to do casts...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Oded is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292740/get-property-from-a-generic-object-in-c/4292764#4292764), it doesn't seem (to him or me) to make any sense to try and make this method generic. You are trying to genericize a method whose functionality is actually specific to a few types.

Now, that said, it seems the *bulk* of the function is independent of this property you want to access. So why not split it into two parts: that which can be genericized, and that which can't:

Something like this:

```
void BindElements<T, TProperty>(IEnumerable<T> dataObjects,
                                Func<T, TProperty> selector)
{
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

    foreach (T item in dataObjects)
    {
       // Notice: by delegating the only type-specific aspect of this method
       // (the property) to (fittingly enough) a delegate, we are able to 
       // package MOST of the code in a reusable form.
       var property = selector(item);

       InlineUIContainer uiContainer = this.CreateElementContainer(property)
       para.Inlines.Add(uiContainer);
    }

    FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument(para);
    this.Document = flowDoc;
}
```

Then your overloads dealing with specific types, e.g., `IPerson`, can reuse this code (which I suspect may be what you were after all along—code reuse):

```
public void BindPeople(IEnumerable<IPerson> people)
{
    BindElements(people, p => p.FirstName);
}
```

...then for `IOrder`:

```
public void BindOrders(IEnumerable<IOrder> orders)
{
    BindElements(orders, o => p.OrderNumber);
}
```

...and so on.

Comment: ah I thought I already commented this ok I do now so...: @Dan Tao => What if I would like to pass TWO of those "selector" like FirstName and LastName, how would the BindElements method parameter change? I have never seed/read of that TProperty + selector nor do I really understand it ;-) just starting doing the really generic generic stuff.

Comment: +1 - Definitely a favorable implemention and what I was thinking where Func could be some sort of factory method for her element container creations.

Answer (score 4):

If you add a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to the generic type (say it has to implement the `IPerson` interface), you can use any methods defined on the interface:

```
public void BindElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataObjects) where T : IPerson
```

If `IPerson` defines `FirstName` and `LastName` peroperties, you can use them with `T`.

See the link for the different types of [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) possible.

Comment: Beat me to it.  My answer would have been almost exactly the same.

Comment: @Oded sorry for confusing it should not mean ...is an IEnumerable it should mean ICustomer or IOrder etc... but you already got it nearly... The problem is I can not put IPerson there because that would destroy the generic function of that method! The User of the UserControl which is exposing the public BindElements method is passing a List<T>, or IEnumerable<T> and T could be IPerson or ICustomer or IOrder, you get it?

Comment: @Lisa - But by wanting to have _specific_ methods to call on your generic parameter you are already "destroying" the generic nature of the function. Please explain _why_ several overloads will not work better than a bastardized generic function?

Comment: @Oded her bastardized generic function would not work anyway if the different entities didn't all have a FirstName property, reflection or not.

Comment: @siride - well aware of that. Which is why I am questioning the generic approach in the first place.

Comment: @Oded I guess I should have directed that at her, for clarification.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Oded - Perhaps she wants to reuse her method logic w/o code duplication since the method seems to just be adding element containers. However, since it needs to support IPerson, ICustomer, and IOrder, perhaps it'd be better to use several overloads that can delegate the call to her generic function with use of an element container factory?

Comment: @Oded => I do not nothing with the entity like IPerson, just get the DisplayMember for the UserControls`s TextBox. Atm I have it where T : class because List<int> which is value type is not allowed only objects with properties. I could use the DisplayMember pass by the User and via reflection propertyInfo.GetValue(dataObject) I could retrieve the value of the DisplayMember which is a property of the item.XXX

Comment: @bitxwise or she can have a IPerson, ICustomer and IOrder inherit from a base interface that contains properties and methods common to all.

Comment: @bitxwise AND siride => There is no base class I can use. This UserControl must work with an existing application and the same time be independant from this application... @bitxwise what you say is right, I just add those containers AND grab the DisplayMember Property from the item not more!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Dan's answer, `Func<T, TProperty> selector` merely says that `selector` is an identifier for a method that takes in a parameter of type `T` and has a return type of `TProperty`. So, a valid method that could be passed into `BindElements` as a second parameter would be, for example,

```
string CreatePersonElement(IPerson person) {
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
}
```

In this case, `TProperty` would be a `string` and `T` would `IPerson`. You can then call `BindElements` like so

```
BindElements(myPersonCollection,CreatePersonElement);
```

where myPersonCollection can just be whatever `List<T>` you were referring to. Then moving on to the foreach loop

```
foreach (T item in dataObjects) {
   // Notice: by delegating the only type-specific aspect of this method
   // (the property) to (fittingly enough) a delegate, we are able to 
   // package MOST of the code in a reusable form.
   var property = selector(item);

   InlineUIContainer uiContainer = this.CreateElementContainer(property)
   para.Inlines.Add(uiContainer);
}
```

`property` is being set to an object of type `TProperty`, which in the case of `CreatePersonElement` is a `string`. If a `string` doesn't work for you, just change the return type of the method to be whatever `CreateElementContainer` is accepting as its parameter.

You would then have one of these methods to pass into the second parameter for `BindElements` for each type you want to support (i.e. `ICustomer`, `IOrder`).

Comment: not the solution bitxwise, but worth a BIG point :P thanks for the sample!

Comment: You're welcome - and yeah, Dan definitely deserves credit for the solution =)

Answer (score 0):

I would read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx and think about Oded's answer again.