# Accessing object's property inside generic method

Tags: c#

How can access the property of an object inside generic method?
I can't use `where T: A` because this method will receive different objects, but all objects have a common property to work on.
(I also can't make for them a common interface)

```
public class A
{
    public int Number {get;set;}
}


List<A> listA = new List<A>{
                new A {Number =4},
                new A {Number =1},
                new A {Number =5}
};

Work<A>(listA);

public static void Work<T>(List<T> list1)
{
    foreach(T item in list1)
    {
        do something with item.Number;
    }
}
```

An update: I need also to set the property

Comment: why can't you create an interface? Sounds like a design problem.

Comment: try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292740/get-property-from-a-generic-object-in-c

Comment: An interface should be the answer otherwise you should test the class in your foreach.

Answer (score 8):

You have a few choices:

- Make a common interface.
- Use reflection.
- Use the dynamic type in .NET 4.

I know you said you can't do the first, but it's the best option for performance and maintainability so please reconsider if its possible before choosing one of the other methods. Remember that even if you can't modify the original code you might still be able to choose the first option. For example if your classes are partial classes you can implement the interface in another file:

File 1:

```
// Automatically generated code that you can't change.
partial class A
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

File 2:

```
interface IHasNumber
{
    int Number { get; set; }
}

partial class A : IHasNumber
{
}
```

If the original class isn't defined as partial you could write wrapper classes around them that implement the interface.

Once you have the common interface you can change your generic constraint to require this interface:

```
where T : IHasNumber
```

Comment: third option - i use net 3.5. , p.s. the objects I pass are entityobjects if it helps.

Comment: ?? How would using .net 3.5 change anything?

Comment: Pierreten, if you look on his answer you'll see "Use the dynamic type in .NET 4."

Comment: @asker: It was only that one line that is specific to .NET 4. The rest of the answer all applies to .NET 3.5.

Comment: @ Mark Byers, sure thing I notted "third option - i use net 3.5"

Comment: Fourth option, don't use *generics* at all if you're creating code that's *specific* to a *particular* type. (Note the emphasis.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the list - just the items, I would use a projection *outside* the method:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<A> listA = new List<A>{
            new A {Number =4},
            new A {Number =1},
            new A {Number =5}
    };

    Work(listA.Select(a => a.Number));

}
public static void Work(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
    foreach (number item in items)
    {
        // do something with number;
    }
}
```

If you need the list - a projection *inside* the method via a selector:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<A> listA = new List<A>{
            new A {Number =4},
            new A {Number =1},
            new A {Number =5}
    };

    Work(listA, a => a.Number);

}
public static void Work<T>(IList<T> list, Func<T, int> selector)
{
    foreach (T obj in list)
    {
        int number = selector(obj);
        // do something with number;
    }
}
```

Comment: with projection I can only get and not to set the property?

Comment: @asker - yes, but if you wanted to set them you should perhaps have said that in the question? "do something with item.Number;" is a bit vague...